# Generate report dynamically given monthA-monthB using SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

The idea is to generate sales report dynamically given 2 months.

For example Report by Category:

Given: January to March

I would like to query the total sales per category from January to March.

How should I do that with SQL Server, MVC and LINQ? If LINQ is not enough then I'm open for the previous SQLxxx.

Thanks,
czetsuya

Answer (score 0):

take the sum(field)

with form and to date's in the where clause

hope this will help you

thanks .